# Providing logical answers

Tags: discussion

Is it allowed to provide logical answers to a question, even if he don't know the syntax of a language. Such as using conditions, loops, etc.

In some cases it cannot be provided as comment, because it need a large explanation or a good formatted code will do more than an explanation.

For eg:

The OP is getting data from a db or any. He was able to do that. Now he need to group every 3 items or so and he don't know how to do.

Now this may be tricky. If there is no straight way of achieving this, we can do so by

```
if (item_num % 3 == 0){//do something}
```

One knows the trick, but he don't know the syntax of the language the OP is using.

Can he provide the answer and disclaiming potential syntax errors

Comment: Can you not find enough questions to answer about languages you actually know? Hard to believe, there are a *lot* of questions...

Comment: @CodyGray Maybe he's a PHP dev ;)

Comment: @CodyGray when surfing through javascript tag, i found the question. Later I understood he was using PHP. He tagged both.

Comment: Pretty basic guidance is *never guess*.  If you feel like opening the answer with "Try this" then it is not an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, to your extremely trivial example: yes, of course you can post an answer with pseudo-code explaining you can use the modulo operator to select every third item.

In practice: no, you need to have *some* experience in the tags you want to post answers to, and most questions aren't so trivial. If they are, they're bound to be a duplicate of another question.

Sure, the modulo operator (or any other trivial, conceptual answer that uses a certain technique) may be available for the language in question, but it may not be the idiomatic way to solve problems like that in that way.

So in order to not cause confusion, or even risk suggesting bad practices, don't post an answer if you're not absolutely sure that it's actually properly solving the question's problem.

Answer (score 3):

You *can*.  The readers of that post may or may not feel that the answer is a quality answer as a result of the syntax problems, or even a lack of code entirely.  Whether or not no-code, or pseudocode, answer to a question can be a quality answer is going to depend on the question.

Some questions are inherently *about* the details of the syntax, rather than an understanding of the approach to the problem, so it's unlikely that an answer you describe would be helpful to such a question.

Other questions are inherently about the approach to solving the problem, the algorithm, etc., and not the ability of the reader to implement that algorithm.  For those, an answer that describes the approach and/or uses pseudocode rather than actual code may well be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid doing so and prefer answering in tags where you are confident about your knowledge.

You definitely can provide such answers - that definitely would be an answer. Beware that quality is hard to predict if you don't know the target language/framework - you may be suggesting non-optimal or even completely wrong solution (i.e. in [C#]+[Linq-toSql] question suggesting to use many regular C# operations is wrong as it can't be converted to SQL).

But I believe you should not do that at least for trivial questions like this that should be answered with basic search. For such questions non-language specific answer is unlikely to help OP (as they already demonstrated inability to search and understand answers that are not exactly copy-paste ready) nor help future visitors (as there will be none as there is likely better answer to the problem).